# How do I manually wind up film without exposing it?

Tags: film, 35mm, darkroom

I've adapted my Diana f+ a little bit and I use 35mm film in it instead of 120 film.

However when I've finished taking pictures on the film and I need to wind it back up, I have to take the film out and wind it up manually myself and that get's a little bit tricky because if you're standing somewhere completely dark, you can't see what you're doing, and I've damaged the film in the past

And I don't know if standing in a dark room will expose the film?
SO my question is, if I stood in a dark room to wind the film back up myself, will that work?

Comment: A rule of thumb (or at least -my- rule of thumb) to determine whether a room is dark enough to handle unprotected film is to go into the room, wait 5 - 10 minutes to (somewhat) accustom your eyes to the dark, and then look at a white sheet of paper. If you can't see it, it's dark enough.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, if the room is truly dark and you work quickly, you'll be fine.  But the room has to be totally dark.  If you have a bathroom or walk-in closet with no windows, and you make sure no light is coming in through under the door, you shoudl be fine.  Wait a few minutes in the dark for your eyes to adjust, to make sure you can't see any light around the doorway.

Easiest thing is to purchase a [film changing bag](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009R6PX).  This is a light-proof bag with openings for your arms.  You put the camera in the bag, zip it up, place your arms through the holes and can then take out the film and rewind it safely.  You still can't see what you're doing, but you don't need a dark room.

Comment: I suggest trying this out a few times with bad rolls or rolls that are already exposed! You don't want your first try of this to be with an important roll of film!

Comment: You can probably go to your local film processor, even Target or Walmart. They usually have film changing boxes for this kind of thing, ask to borrow it at the counter, and feel your way through it...take your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to have any light on when dealing with undeveloped film. Its either a film changing bag, or a darkroom with no safelight. You have to learn to do it by feel. If you can see anything even after several minutes letting your eyes adjust, its too much light.

Print paper can handle safe lights, but even they have to be dim and you have to let your eyes adjust.